# access another firestore data in angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am holding 2 firebase projects(A & B) having data in firestore and not in realtime. 
My use case is I need to access other project's firestore data. A app should be able to read & write B's firestore and vice-versa.

I tried like let's take from A app standpoint, we can access A's firestore data using **public afs: AngularFirestore** that comes from the constructor. But to access B's firestore data, I tried to initialize the config and take angularfirestore reference like below.

```
const secondApp = firebase.initializeApp({
          apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx"
          });
const secondAfS = new AngularFirestore(secondApp );
```

Then it ended up by throwing the error as  `Expected 6 arguments, but got 1.`

I am not sure about the parameters required for constructor but just tried. So the error says(To me), Does it works if we supply required 6 parameters?

Is this kind of use case achievable? if so, please correct me.
Otherwise, please advise me the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I did not find an option to call another firestore database but we can call another realtime database. So I managed to achieve my functionality by adding database triggers in realtime database of another app.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at [the source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/53ad0d8c73fbad785787d530f7ef0635e2422406/src/firestore/firestore.ts#L106) it seems that there's no way to pass a `FirebaseApp` instance into AngularFirestore. Instead you pass the options and config into the `AngularFirestore` constructor, and it creates the `FirebaseApp` itself.

So something like this:

```
const secondConfig = {
          apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx"
          };
const secondAfS = new AngularFirestore(secondConfig);
```

Comment: No luck, same error. **Expected 6 arguments, but got 1.**